# Can we populate the QueryString Parameters and values from Parameter sets?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, load-testing, querystringparameter, web-performance

How should i configure my URL based load test in VSTS such that i can repeat the load test with different parameter values.
Can I load the parameters and values from Parameter sets ? If yes, How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can load the parameters and values from the Query String Parameters. It will add the string `?para=value` in the URL you configured. But it cannot repeat the load test with different parameter values. The feature you want to achieve is Data-Driven test, you can refer to this article to setup it: [Data-Driven Load Tests using Visual Studio Online and SQL Azure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/08/26/data-driven-load-tests-using-visual-studio-online-and-sql-azure/).